# neither Picasso nor glide display images in my app

Tags: android

I am creating a movie app that has two fragment to show now playing movies and upcoming movies now i am creating now playing fragment and i use item_movie layout that has cardview as root and relativelayout and within this two textview and imageview and i am using Picasso to load images my problem is images don't appear but textviews are displayed i tried to find answer for several hours but i didn't that go me crazy here is the code for Now playing fragment

```
package com.example.moviemanager.fragment;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.moviemanager.R;
import com.example.moviemanager.adapters.MovieRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.example.moviemanager.models.Movie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NowPlayingFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView rcmovies;
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public NowPlayingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_now_playing, container, false);

        initializeData();

        rcmovies= view.findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);
        LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        rcmovies.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rcmovies.setLayoutManager(llm);
        MovieRecyclerViewAdapter adapter=new MovieRecyclerViewAdapter(this.getContext(),movies);
        rcmovies.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;

    }


    private void initializeData() {
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        movies.add(new Movie("277834", "Moana", "In Ancient Polynesia, when a terrible curse incurred by Maui reaches an impetuous Chieftain's daughter's island, she answers the Ocean's call to seek out the demigod to set things right.", 6.5f, 854, "/z4x0Bp48ar3Mda8KiPD1vwSY3D8.jpg", "/1qGzqGUd1pa05aqYXGSbLkiBlLB.jpg"));
        movies.add(new Movie("121856", "Passengers", "A spacecraft traveling to a distant colony planet and transporting thousands of people has a malfunction in its sleep chambers. As a result, two passengers are awakened 90 years early.", 6.2f,  745, "/5gJkVIVU7FDp7AfRAbPSvvdbre2.jpg", "/5EW4TR3fWEqpKsWysNcBMtz9Sgp.jpg"));
        movies.add(new Movie("330459", "Assassin's Creed", "Lynch discovers he is a descendant of the secret Assassins society through unlocked genetic memories that allow him to relive the adventures of his ancestor, Aguilar, in 15th Century Spain. After gaining incredible knowledge and skills he’s poised to take on the oppressive Knights Templar in the present day.", 5.3f, 691, "/tIKFBxBZhSXpIITiiB5Ws8VGXjt.jpg", "/5EW4TR3fWEqpKsWysNcBMtz9Sgp.jpg"));
        movies.add(new Movie("283366", "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story", "A rogue band of resistance fighters unite for a mission to steal the Death Star plans and bring a new hope to the galaxy.", 7.2f, 1802, "/qjiskwlV1qQzRCjpV0cL9pEMF9a.jpg", "/tZjVVIYXACV4IIIhXeIM59ytqwS.jpg"));
        movies.add(new Movie("313369", "La La Land", "Mia, an aspiring actress, serves lattes to movie stars in between auditions and Sebastian, a jazz musician, scrapes by playing cocktail party gigs in dingy bars, but as success mounts they are faced with decisions that begin to fray the fragile fabric of their love affair, and the dreams they worked so hard to maintain in each other threaten to rip them apart.", 8, 396, "/ylXCdC106IKiarftHkcacasaAcb.jpg", "/nadTlnTE6DdgmYsN4iWc2a2wiaI.jpg"));


    }

}
```

and the adapter

```
public class MovieRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieRecyclerViewAdapter.viewholder> {

     Context context;
     List<Movie> movies;
public MovieRecyclerViewAdapter (Context context,List<Movie>movies){
    this.context=context;
    this.movies=movies;
    }


    private Context getContext(){
    return context;
    }
    @Override
    public viewholder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int i) {

        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_movie,parent,false);
        return new viewholder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( viewholder holder, int pos) {

Movie movie=movies.get(pos);
holder.tvTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
holder.tvoverview.setText(movie.getOverview());
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(movie.getPosterPath()).into(holder.ivmovieimage);
        //Glide.with(getContext()).load(movie.getPosterPath()).into(holder.ivmovieimage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }
    public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView tvTitle;
TextView tvoverview;
ImageView ivmovieimage;
        public viewholder( View view) {
            super(view);
            tvTitle=view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvoverview=view.findViewById(R.id.tvOverView);
            ivmovieimage=view.findViewById(R.id.ivMovieImage);
        }
    }
}
```

then create a model to hold all data here is

```
package com.example.moviemanager.models;

public class Movie {
    String id;
    String title;
    String overview;
    float voteAverage;
    float voteCount;
    String posterPath;
    String backdropPath;
    public Movie(String id, String title, String overview, float voteAverage, float voteCount, String posterPath, String backdropPath) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public float getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(float voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public float getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(float voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return  String.format( "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342",posterPath);
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath =posterPath;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

}
```

and the item movie xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cvMovie"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMovieImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivMovieImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivMovieImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_small_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_small_margin"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            tool:text="Captain America" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOverView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_small_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_small_margin"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivMovieImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivMovieImage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:text="Captain America OverView"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.NowPlayingFragment">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvMovies"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and for the content_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I use internet permission in manifest
these about the whole app

Comment: Add `android:layout_width="match_parent"` & `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in `ImageView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this in your url %s

```
  String.format( "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342%s",posterPath)
```

because you have not define in what way you want to format the string

[image]

Comment: yes it work but what is arguments of String.format() and what it does?

Comment: The java string format() method returns a formatted string using the given locale, specified format string and arguments.We can concatenate the strings using this method and at the same time, we can format the output concatenated string you even try this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-examples/)